# "either" or "neither" after "I don't like..."

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

Consider this fill-in-the-blank question:

> I don't like _______ of the films. Both of them are boring.

Will the correct choice will be **either** OR **neither**? Why? I think the correct answer will be "either" but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Standard English has a single negative:

- "I don't like **either** of the films", or
- "I like **neither** of the films"

Also:

- "I don't like **any** of the films"
- "I like **none** of the films"